# airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces

Tags: kali-linux, network-interface, vmware, airmon-ng

I try to start wifite on VMware (Kali) but doesnt work, is there a possibility to use the local network card (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168) to let search the VM for available networks?

This is the error message i received:

```
root@kali:~# wifite
   .               .    
 .´  ·  .     .  ·  `.  wifite 2.2.5
 :  :  :  (¯)  :  :  :  automated wireless auditor
 `.  ·  ` /¯\ ´  ·  .´  https://github.com/derv82/wifite2
   `     /¯¯¯\     ´    
 [!] Warning: Recommended app pyrit was not found. install @ https://github.com/JPaulMora/Pyrit/wiki
 [!] Warning: Recommended app hcxdumptool was not found. install @ https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxdumptool
 [!] Warning: Recommended app hcxpcaptool was not found. install @ https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools
 [!] Conflicting processes: NetworkManager (PID 555), wpa_supplicant (PID 739), dhclient (PID 1454)
 [!] If you have problems: kill -9 PID or re-run wifite with --kill)
 [+] Checking airmon-ng...                                                                                                                                                               
 [!] airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces
 [!] Make sure your wireless device is connected
 [!] See http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng for more info
 [!] Error: airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces
 [!] Full stack trace below
 [!]    Traceback (most recent call last):
 [!]    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wifite/__main__.py", line 93, in entry_point
 [!]        wifite.start()
 [!]    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wifite/__main__.py", line 53, in start
 [!]        Configuration.get_monitor_mode_interface()
 [!]    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wifite/config.py", line 129, in get_monitor_mode_interface
 [!]        cls.interface = Airmon.ask()
 [!]    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wifite/tools/airmon.py", line 299, in ask
 [!]        raise Exception('airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces')
 [!]  Exception: airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces
 [!] Exiting*
```

Comment: Unless passed to the VM the actual network connection doesn't matter because virtualization will use an emulated Ethernet connection which is not compatible with the use you want. But if using Kali you should know that and a lot more already.

Comment: does not work
it says unable to fetch some archives,maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix missing? I did what his E does not work anything

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install pyrit
sudo apt-get install hcxdumptool
sudo apt-get install hcxtools
```

and say yes to everything. After that, all recommended apps have been installed.